# Un-synced reputation? (Should I blame caching?)

Tags: support, reputation, top-bar, communities-list

Why is my reputation on the notif-bar and the drop-down menu different!?

```
Notif-bar: 711
Drop-down: 710
```

[image: YA SEE IT ALL]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Thank you for giving me a site with the words "Yes" and some tiny grey words! +1

Comment: The title of the site is "Should I blame caching?" The answer given by the site is "Yes." I linked to it because that is probably the answer to your question.

Comment: Answer "yes" then.

Comment: I think you're missing a bit of context. We get questions on this site all the time asking about desynchronized values in various places. That site is often linked to both because it points out that the answer is probably caching and because it points out that this sort of problem is so common in general that someone made a site dedicated to pointing out that the answer is almost always caching. The real point is that if you ever run into such an issue again, you can remember that it's probably caching and see it resolved just by waiting a little while.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't really experienced a caching-caused problem before, so I don't have much experience on resolving them.

Comment: You should [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but I feel so bad for the old me 1 year ago who was being rude because he didn't understand the joke. :|

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those values are all cached. They will reflect the values currently cached for your [list of network accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/4596673/arceusmaster0493?tab=accounts). They update regularly about every 10 minutes, but not instantly.